# Environment Deployment Process

Tags: 8, deployment

Here's a quick rundown of what I've done. (Bear in mind I'm still fairly new to this whole Drupal environment):

- Started my site in a Dev environment using the drupal-composer
  project: `composer create-project
  drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev project_name --stability dev
  --no-interaction`
- Installed a bunch of modules including config_installer
- Created a bunch of content types, taxonomies, node, etc.
- Pushed it all into a git repository
- Set up a few other servers for another Developer Environment, Test & Production environment.

I'm now in the process of taking what I've done to the other development environment and seem to be stuck on this point.

I've cloned my project to this new server and then run `composer install --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader` and gone through the install.php process and selected the config_installer profile to import my configuration from the other server. All went well, except at the very end of the installer, I get an HTML page that just spits out a lot of code. If I go to the homepage URL after this, it all seems good with my theme/layout working as well as a few view pages.

My issue now is that I can't seem to log in to my user account or see some of the blocks/pages I've created as well as some taxonomies that I've used as filters on a view. I understand that this is all tied into the database so I'm assuming that I need to export the database over to the rest of my environments also, correct?

But what happens when I'm testing things in my dev environment after there's content in my other environments? Am I able to merge the databases or am I going to have to repeat the same process in my production site and then just import the configuration? I guess I'm having a difficult time wrapping this whole process around in my head.

Perhaps someone can clarify this a little better for me as I've spent much of the day trying to figure this out.

Comment: The easiest approach imo is using a service like Travis or CircleCI, letting it package up the artifact to a git branch and it deploys to the proper environment automatically based on source branch.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Kevin but unfortunately, we aren't able to take that approach. I guess all I really need answered is my question about the databases.

Comment: Why not? If you use something like Acquia BLT (can be added to existing projects) they have a `deploy` command that will do this _without needing_ a CI service. It will build on your machine and push out. Taking either route will solve all the questions you have, leaving you to just `drush @alias cim` when needed. When it comes to replicating up, I will move the databases up from dev to prime them. After that, I only move them down (prod through dev). Everything else I need is contained in the code itself.